# Approach to achieve SSO with ASP.Net application and SAML Enabled app

Tags: asp.net, saml

I currently have a web application that is on the 4.0 framework without WIF installed, and I have a requirement to have SSO with a vendor application using the IDP-initated flow of SAML.

The requirement doesn't allow me to install .net 4.5 nor WIF. So, I was thinking to create a separate project (share machine keys with the first project) and then use the owin pipeline to integrate with my IDP.

I was curious to see if there are any other options or if my approach would work.